# How would you be able to use fast-json package in the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, requirejs

I have been browsing ways on how I could improve my apps performance and came across these 2 packages. I am building a forum styled app that receives a bunch of information from APIs and regularly parses and stringifies it. I have already optimized my front end JS as much as I could(it's just vanilla JS at this point) but it sometimes still struggles to load on older phones. I would love to try these packages as they could potentially relieve my issue but they are both in NPM form.

I would like to use them in my browser UI scripts.Is there any way to use NPM packages directly in browser/ can you get a single script version of them?

Specifically:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-json
https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-json-stringify

Comment: Have you read the documentation for those packages?

Comment: @JaromandaX Roughly but they both use require statements (meant for Node). But I believe they should be able to run in the browser too.

Comment: There's references to v8 engine optimisations. So. Whatever those libraries claim, it'll only be for those obscure browsers that use v8. You know.  Like chrome and edge. Anyway, those libraries are definitley for node only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple!

1. Copy the code from [fast-json/blob/master/lib/EventTree.js](https://github.com/alemures/fast-json/blob/master/lib/EventTree.js) in your source code, but without module.exports block (is to bottom of the code)
2. Copy the code from [fast-json/blob/master/lib/FastJson.js](https://github.com/alemures/fast-json/blob/master/lib/FastJson.js) in your source code, but without `const { EventTree } = require('./EventTree');` (at top) and without `module.exports = FastJson;` (bottom)
3. TEST TIME ^_^

```
const fastJson = new FastJson();

// Path is a string representing a javascript object path
fastJson.on('ireland.people', (value) => {  
    console.log('ireland.people ->', value);
});

// Paths can be also an array of keys 
fastJson.on(['spain', 'people', '1', 'name'], (value) => {   
    console.log(['spain', 'people', '1','name'], '->', value); 
});

// Wildcards can be used to match all items in object or array
fastJson.on('spain.people[*].name', (value) => {  
    console.log('spain.people[*].name ->', value); 
});

fastJson.on('*.people[*].name', (value) => {  
    console.log('*.people[*].name ->', value); 
});

fastJson.write(data);
```